# How do i get all children (ie children of children) with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, prototypejs

I need a javascript function or a CSS Selector (or even a **ProtoypeJS** function) which gets me ALL elements (ie. descendants) under a particular element.

I understand there are CSS selectors such as : **'p, a, div'**, which would get me all the elements of those three types. However I need to get EVERYTHING without specifying type.

ie. I want something like

```
myElement.getElements('*')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compatible with all versions of IE, not just IE8+...

```
myElement.getElementsByTagName("*")
```

`*` is treated as a special case for `getElementsByTagName` to return all descendants regardless of tag name. (This is different to `querySelectorAll`, where `*` is a genuine selector that matches all elements)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll)

```
myElement.querySelectorAll('*')
```

Note: [Supported in IE8+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Wouldn't `getElementsByTagName("*")` be more old-browser-compatible?

Comment: I figured you could just edit yours, but okay then ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The method that will get you all child elements as an extended PrototypeJS array is `childElements()` http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/childElements/

```
element.childElements()
```

For other situations you might want to narrow down the child elements that are returned you can use `select()`

```
element.select('div')
```

will return all the div children of `element`

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to do this with CSS alone. The `*` (universal) selector targets all elements. If you want to target all children of a specific `element`, then you can simply do this:

```
element * {}
```